# SQL Server 2008 R2 to MongoDB - is it safe to migrate?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, migration, asp.net-4.0

We are running a .Net 4.0 ASP.Net application with SQL Server 2008 R2. I often face database related issues and have to frequently look into possibilities of optimising my SQL code (procedures, triggers, jobs etc). I recently, came to know about MongoDB and read a few articles about it.

Invariably, all articles show that Mongo is much much faster than SQL Server 2008 R2 in CRUD operations.

I also read that sourceforge has migrated from MySQL to MongoDB and claim to be capable of handling 100x more data.

So, impressed with these stats, I went to the mongoDB site, I followed their short demo. It was nice. But I couldn't find much information about other database related aspects like SProcs, triggers, jobs, cursors, Key, indexes etc.

What is my main concern is that is MongoDB evolved enough that I can think of migrating from SQL Server 2008 R2. Also, things like Keys, Indexex, SProcs, triggers, SQL jobs etc do they exist in MongoDB as well? How good is their .Net integration API?

Does anybody have any idea about it?

Thanking in anticipation

Answer (score 4):

What **kind** of issues do you face with SQL Server 2008 R2??

One option might be to figure those out and fix them. If you optimize your stored procs, if you redesign your table and indices to be more efficient, that might be more than enough to keep your app up and running very well.

I don't know MongoDB that well - but the basic approach is very different - instead of rows and columns and relations, you have "documents". As far as I know, MongoDB does not have any construct similar to stored procedures or triggers - all that would have to be handled in your application.

So it really depends on what kind of app you have - something like an accounting application is probably better off in SQL Server 2008 R2, while something else might be more suitable for MongoDB.

I don't think switching to MongoDB is a "quick fix" just for any kind of performance problems...

Also check out this other SO post on the very same topic:

[Reasons for and against moving from SQL server to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287966/reasons-for-and-against-moving-from-sql-server-to-mongodb)

Comment: +1. Relational databases are seriously capable if running with proper hardware and good programming, which sometimes is really not the case (programming close to abuse is something i often see). Mongodb etc. are document stores - they have advvantags and disadvantages. Knowing how they fit you is core to actually be able to really use them. I have a lot of apps that just dont follow the "document" approach.

Comment: You simply will not find the same feature set in Mongo as you have in SQL Server, a solution that is over 10+ years old and really rock solid in most applications IF programmed and administered well.

Comment: Only use MongoDB if you need a non-relational solution. For instance, if you find yourself having to do a lot of dynamic queries and especially if you have a dynamic schema and/or a key-value table, then you are stepping into an area which is much better implemented with MongoDB